# Should I implement father interface in the child?

Tags: oop, inheritance, interface

If I'm writing a class that inherits from another, which implement an interface, should I implement this interface in the child?

```
class FatherClass implements MyInterface
{
    ...
}

public class ChildClass extends FatherClass { // Should I implement MyInterface here?
    ...
}
```

Comment: You mean you should declare it like `public class ChildClass extends FatherClass implements MyInterface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Implemented interfaces in Parent class are just inherited
- so there's no need to copy and paste "implements SomeInterface" on the children classes. It's not necessary, smarter.
- Having both the child and the parent implement the same Interface has no additional effect.
- It is equivalent to having the parent only implement that interface.